# Using data.table for a conditional sum within groups with lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a `data.table` where each row is an event with a start date and end date, but the number of days between each start and end is variable.
Therefore, I am attempting to count how many other events have already ended at the time each one begins.
I can do this using `lapply`, but when I try to use `data.table` with the `by` functionality I don't get the expected output. Sample code below:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
  start = as.Date(c("2018-07-01","2018-07-03","2018-07-06","2018-07-08","2018-07-12","2018-07-15")),
  end = as.Date(c("2018-07-10","2018-07-04","2018-07-09","2018-07-20","2018-07-14","2018-07-27")),
  group_id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"))

# This produces the expected output (0,0,1,1,3,4):
lapply(DT$start, function(x) sum(x > DT$end))

# This also works using data.table:
DT[, count := lapply(DT$start, function(x) sum(x > DT$end))]

# However, I don't get the expected output (0,0,1,0,0,1) when I attempt to do this by group_id
DT[, count_by_group := lapply(DT$start, function(x) sum(x > DT$end)), by = group_id]
```

With the following output, where `count_by_group` is not the expected result:

```
        start        end group_id count count_by_group
1: 2018-07-01 2018-07-10        a     0              0
2: 2018-07-03 2018-07-04        a     0              0
3: 2018-07-06 2018-07-09        a     1              0
4: 2018-07-08 2018-07-20        b     1              0
5: 2018-07-12 2018-07-14        b     3              0
6: 2018-07-15 2018-07-27        b     4              0
```

Can someone help me understand how `by` changes the behavior? I've also tried to use different versions of the `.SD` feature, but wasn't able to get that to work either.

Comment: `DT[, count_by_group := sapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end)), by = group_id]` . (Lose the `DT$` prefix, and, not sure why yet, prefer `sapply()`)

Comment: (figured out why `sapply`. It's because the RHS of `:=` expects either a vector, or a list of columns. If the column is itself a list, wrapping it in an extra `list()` works: `count_by_group := list(lapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end)))` ...). But then, `count_by_group` is a list-column. I guess `sapply()` or `vapply()` is preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DT[, count_by_group := vapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end), integer(1)), by = group_id]
```

To refer to `start` and `end` by group, we need to leave the `DT$` prefix out.
We use `vapply()` rather than `lapply()` because if the right hand side of `:=` is a list, it is interpreted as a list of columns (and since only one column is expected, only the first element, a `0`, is taken into account and recycled).

Comment: `unlist(lapply(...)` has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

#### `unlist()`

`unlist()` works as well:

```
DT[, count_by_group := unlist(lapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end))), by = group_id]
```

#### Non-equi join

Alternatively, this can also be solved by *aggregating in a non-equi self join*:

```
DT[, count_by_group := DT[DT, on = .(group_id, end < start), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
DT
```

> ```
>         start        end group_id count_by_group
> 1: 2018-07-01 2018-07-10        a              0
> 2: 2018-07-03 2018-07-04        a              0
> 3: 2018-07-06 2018-07-09        a              1
> 4: 2018-07-08 2018-07-20        b              0
> 5: 2018-07-12 2018-07-14        b              0
> 6: 2018-07-15 2018-07-27        b              1
> ```

#### Benchmark

The non-equi join is also the fastest method for cases with more than a few hundred rows:

```
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  n_grp = c(2L, 5L, 10L),
  n_row = 10^(2:4),
  {
    set.seed(1L)
    DT = data.table(
      group_id = sample.int(n_grp, n_row, TRUE),
      start = as.Date("2018-07-01") + rpois(n_row, 20L))
    DT[, end := start + rpois(n_row, 10L)]
    setorder(DT, group_id, start, end)
    mark(
      unlist = copy(DT)[, count_by_group := unlist(lapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end))), by = group_id],
      sapply = copy(DT)[, count_by_group := sapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end)), by = group_id],
      vapply = copy(DT)[, count_by_group := vapply(start, function(x) sum(x > end), integer(1)), by = group_id],
      nej = copy(DT)[, count_by_group := DT[DT, on = .(group_id, end < start), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
    )
  }
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

For 10000 rows, the non-equi join is about 10 times faster than the other methods.

As `DT` is being updated, `copy()` is used to create a fresh, unmodified  copy of `DT` for each benchmark run.